# Error CS0006 No se encontró el archivo de metadatos

Tags: c#, compilar

Cuando le doy ejecutar al proyecto me sale el siguiente mensaje y no se como arreglarlo ya que soy muy novato con c#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421862/metadata-file-dll-could-not-be-found entra aqui